# Interactive plot in R (part scatterplot, part network)

Tags: r, nodes, scatter-plot, interactive, edges

I am trying to build an interactive plot. It has properties between a scatterplot and a network - I have a list of nodes and edges (network), but I also would like to constrain the nodes, sometimes on the x-axis sometimes on both x- and y- axis (scatterplot). Finally, I have a text label associated with each node that I would like to display (instead of a dot). I was able to create this using ggplot2.

However, some data sets are too large for this to work without the text labels from each node overlapping. Hence, I would now like to add an interactive feature so that the plot consists of dots representing each node, but that upon UI (such as hovering over a dot), the text label belonging to that dot will be revealed.

I would like to achieve this using R.

I tried animint (https://github.com/tdhock/animint) but it seems to mostly allow interaction between two plots, and here I would like to keep it all in one plot.

I also tried htmlwidgets (http://www.htmlwidgets.org/). I looked at two of their packages: I tried using metricsgraphics (mjs_plot), as it has a show_rollover_text option and mouseover option. However, this package does not allow combination of geoms, and so I could not have both dots (nodes) and lines (edges) represented. I also tried network3D package, but that seems to automatically position nodes so that they are distanced far away from each other, and does not seem to provide options to fix each node on a given x and y location.

I am just looking for advice on any other packages I should maybe consider to solve this problem and/or if I may be missing a feature from a package I already tried that could solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `identify()` will be useful for you. But it works only for base plotting system.

```
x <- rnorm(300)
y <- rnorm(300)
labs <- seq(300)
plot(x,y)
identify(x,y, labels = labs, plot=TRUE)
```

[identify pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA6Sd.png)